# How to iterate over an dataframe object list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataset with a lot of `int`, `float` and `object` variables. I've used the code bellow to extract only the name of the `object` variables into a `list`.

```
objects = df.dtypes[df.dtypes == "object"].index
objects = list(objects)
```

And now I want to plot all these variables against another variable `Y`. I'm trying to do something like that but it's not working. See the code bellow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

i = 0 
for i in objects:
   plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
   sns.boxplot(df.objects[i], df.Y)
   i = i+1
```

I'm new to `Python` and I don't exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is the code in the `for` not indented or is it only like that here in the question? What i'm trying to say is make sure the indentation in the question matches your code exactly. Also that's not how you loop over objects in python.

Comment: The code in the `for` is indented. It was a mistake here when I posted the question but I just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find an answer. The code bellow do what I was trying to do. It plots two boxplots against variable `Y`, one at a time.

```
objects = ['A', 'B']

for obj in objects: 
   plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
   sns.boxplot(df[obj], df.Y)
```